# Ploting a function in Julia

Tags: julia, plots.jl

I would like to plot following mathematical modell of the p-V-diagramm

[image]

However, when I try to plot the function I get a different plot.

```
T0 = 492
V0 = 275
Tmax = 25
Vmax = 75
vals = []

for t in range(1,stop=2*π,length=30)
    push!(vals, (T0 + Tmax*sin(t))/(V0-Vmax*cos(t)))
end

plot(vals, legend=nothing)
```

[image]

I am not sure if I am using plots right.

Comment: You're missing the y part, e.g. `plot(vals, append!(collect(1:15), collect(reverse(1:15))))`.

Comment: @AndreWildberg Thanks seems to work. However the plot is cut in halve. In other words, how can I "zoom out" of the plot to see the entire function?

Comment: This was just a toy example. The values should be generated according to the requirements of the function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

reference:

- https://docs.juliaplots.org/latest/input_data/#Functions
- https://docs.juliaplots.org/latest/generated/gr/#gr-ref3

```
julia> T0 = 492

julia> V0 = 275

julia> Tmax = 25

julia> Vmax = 75

julia> using Plots

julia> V(t) = V0-Vmax*cos(t)
V (generic function with 1 method)

julia> P(t) = (T0 + Tmax*sin(t))/V(t)
P (generic function with 1 method)

julia> plot(V, P, 0:0.1:2pi)
```

[image]